# belongstomany return empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have created relationship `belongsToMany` in laravel 4. This return empty array and i don't know why, because when i add same SQL in database i get results.

I have tried this:

```
public function modules() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Module', 'license_module', 'id_license', 'id_modul')->withPivot('expiration')->orderby('expiration', 'asc');
}
```

This is call example:

```
Company::find($companyID)->modules()->get();
```

This is getQueryLog() example:

```
[14] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `bb_companies` where `bb_companies`.`id_company` = ? limit 1
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100001
                )

            [time] => 0.26
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [query] => select `bb_modules`.*, `bb_license_module`.`id_license` as `pivot_id_license`, `bb_license_module`.`id_modul` as `pivot_id_modul`, `bb_license_module`.`expiration` as `pivot_expiration` from `bb_modules` inner join `bb_license_module` on `bb_modules`.`id_modul` = `bb_license_module`.`id_modul` where `bb_license_module`.`id_license` = ?
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100001
                )

            [time] => 0.19
        )
```

If i remove `->orderby('expiration', 'asc');` nothing happens.

This is plain sql:

```
select * from `bb_modules` inner join `bb_license_module` on `bb_modules`.`id_modul` = `bb_license_module`.`id_modul` where `bb_license_module`.`id_license` = ? order by `expiration` asc
```

Comment: what is your [`dd(DB::getQueryLog())`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#query-logging) looked like? is it your desired query? also, i wonder if it caused by `->orderby('expiration', 'asc');`, what does happen if it removed?

Comment: @Tezla i have add new answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: weird, i don't see why it should fail.. btw, could you post your plain query (sql)?

Comment: btw...same thing work in Laravel 5